# Is it possible to create a NumPy array of characters and access contiguous slices of that array in constant time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

#### This Is Not a Duplicate

I searched quite a bit, and I'm very aware that many posts already exist on related topics, but not one that I've seen answers this simple question.

#### Question

Is it possible to use NumPy to create an array of characters (let's assume unicode) that then allows contiguous slicing in constant time?

#### Desired Behavior

```
n = 10
chars = 'x' * n
np_chars = np.array(chars)
for i in range(len(np_chars)):
    _ = np_chars[:i] # This line should run in O(1) time, not O(i) time
```

The overall complexity here should be `O(n)`, not `O(n ** 2)`.

#### Actual Behavior

The actual behavior surrounding `np_chars` is one of the most unexpected experiences I've ever had with NumPy. I'm assuming that all of this is intended behavior for good reason, and it would be great if someone can point out what that reason is.

`print(np_chars)` prints `xxxxxxxxxx` (good)

`len(np_chars)` yields the error `TypeError: len() of unsized object` (???)

`np_chars.size` is 1 (???)

`np_chars.shape` is `()` (???)

`np_chars[0]` yields `IndexError: too many indices for array` (???)

`np_chars.dtype` is `dtype('<U10')` (good, I think?)

Based on this last line, I also tried to experiment with the idea of creating an *array of type `<U1`*, thinking that this would perhaps fix any confusion between having 1. an array of length 1 containing 1 string vs. 2. an array of length `n` containing `n` strings of length 1, but this ended up just truncating my string.

Comment: What's wrong with just slicing the string `chars[:i]`?  No need for numpy.

Comment: `np_chars.dtype is dtype('<U10')`

Not good, it means you have an array where the dtype is strings with 10 characters. Change `chars = 'x' * n` to `chars = ['x'] * n` Or call the list constructor inside the array constructor.

Comment: You gave `np.array` one string, and the result is an array with just one string.

Comment: @hpaulj, `chars[:i]` is linear in `i`, not constant (it creates a copy)

Comment: @DavidHoffman, that does seem to be the trick – thanks. If you happen to have any insights into NumPy's odd behavior above, even *given* that it's an array with one string, please do share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [89]: n = 10 
    ...: chars = 'x' * n 
    ...: np_chars = np.array(chars)                                             
In [90]: chars                                                                  
Out[90]: 'xxxxxxxxxx'
```

I don't see anything odd about `np_chars`.  You asked it to make an array from one string.  It did just that:

```
In [91]: np_chars                                                               
Out[91]: array('xxxxxxxxxx', dtype='<U10')
In [92]: np_chars.shape                                                         
Out[92]: ()
In [93]: np_chars[()]                                                           
Out[93]: 'xxxxxxxxxx'
```

`np_chars` is a 0d array with 1 element, that string.  And since it is 0d, it can only be indexed with an empty tuple.

You can make an array from a list of strings, e.g.

```
In [94]: list(chars)                                                            
Out[94]: ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']
In [95]: np.array(list(chars))                                                  
Out[95]: array(['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], dtype='<U1')
```

Getting substrings from a string:

```
In [96]: [chars[:i] for i in range(10)]                                         
Out[96]: 
['',
 'x',
 'xx',
 'xxx',
 'xxxx',
 'xxxxx',
 'xxxxxx',
 'xxxxxxx',
 'xxxxxxxx',
 'xxxxxxxxx']
```

Getting array slices from the character array:

```
In [97]: [_95[:i] for i in range(10)]                                           
Out[97]: 
[array([], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['x'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['x', 'x'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['x', 'x', 'x'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], dtype='<U1')]
```

The array slices are views, so the `O` measure is different, but at least for this size, the string approach is faster.  And creating the array in the first place takes time:

```
In [98]: timeit [chars[:i] for i in range(10)]                                  
1.83 µs ± 23.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [99]: timeit [_95[:i] for i in range(10)]                                    
3.94 µs ± 121 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [100]: timeit np.array(list(chars))                                          
3.95 µs ± 107 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

But the two approaches make such different things, that it doesn't make much sense to compare them.  We could make strings from the array slices, but that takes even more time:

```
In [101]: [''.join(_95[:i]) for i in range(10)]                                 
Out[101]: 
['',
 'x',
 'xx',
 'xxx',
 'xxxx',
 'xxxxx',
 'xxxxxx',
 'xxxxxxx',
 'xxxxxxxx',
 'xxxxxxxxx']
In [102]: timeit [''.join(_95[:i]) for i in range(10)]                          
41.5 µs ± 306 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Even when I increase `n` to 1000, the string slicing is faster.

Comment: Good catch with the "it's just a 0-D array". For some reason that didn't hit me. I am amazed that for example `len(np.array(0))` throws an error, but I guess in the end it does make sense, since e.g. `len(0)` also throws an error.